# Carrito de compras toma solo 1 input de cantidad y no el resto

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema, tengo un carrito que trae items del localstorage, pero quiero calcular los subtotales y el input de el primer item funciona correctamente (console.log), pero el resto no funcionan, les dejo el codigo, muchas gracias

```
    let parsedItems = JSON.parse(itemsLS);
    console.log(parsedItems)


    for(let i = 0; i < parsedItems.length; i++){
    
        let parsedItem = parsedItems[i];
        let cartLSList = document.getElementById('cart');
        let sss = parsedItem.price * parsedItem.quantity;
        cartLSList.innerHTML += `
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="cartArt">
                        <td scope="row"><img src="${parsedItem.img}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="250" height="180"></td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle">${parsedItem.name}</td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle">${parsedItem.price} ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle"><input id="amount" type="number" value="${parsedItem.quantity}" ></td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle" id="totalsub">$ ${sss} ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>   
            </table> 
        `
        document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener('input', function() {
            
            console.log("ola")
        })
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu caso lo puedes solucionar modificando lo siguiente:

1. Donde pone esto:

```
<td scope="row" class="align-middle">${parsedItem.price} ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
```

ponlo así:

```
<td scope="row" class="align-middle"><span class="price">${parsedItem.price}</span> ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
```

porque de este modo encerramos en la clase **price** tan solo el número con el que luego hacer los cálculos, esquivando el símbolo de moneda siguiente.

2. Del mismo modo cambia esto:

```
<td scope="row" class="align-middle" id="totalsub">$ ${sss} ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
```

por esto:

```
<td scope="row" class="align-middle">$ <span class="totalsub">${sss}</span> ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
```

para que después, una vez realizado el cálculo, podamos de nuevo cambiar tan solo el número que se corresponde con el subtotal.

3. Y ahora cambia esto:

```
<input id="amount" type="number" value="${parsedItem.quantity}" >
```

por esto:

```
<input class="amount" type="number" value="${parsedItem.quantity}" >
```

donde evitamos el uso del id para usar tan solo la clase. Los **id** nunca deben repetirse en HTML para evitar comportamientos indeseados e imprevistos según el código de javascript que estés usando con ellos. En tu caso ese era el principal problema para que pudieras continuar.

4. Y para terminar, en lugar de intentar usar un **id** común con addEventListener, ahora puedes hacerlo por clase cambiando esto:

```
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log("ola")
})
```

por esto:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".amount").forEach((x) => x.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let totalsub = x.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".totalsub")
  let price = x.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".price2")
  totalsub.innerHTML = parseInt(price.innerHTML) * x.value
}))
```

lo cual si que va a poner a todos los elementos con la clase común `amount` a la escucha del evento **input**, al cual le pasamos una función que realizará los cálculos que necesitas para modificar el subtotal cuando el valor del input sea modificado.

Enlaces a la documentación de los nuevos métodos o propiedades usados en esta respuesta:

- [`<span></span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Función de flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)
- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

### Ejemplo completo

```js
let parsedItems = [{
    img: "ruta1",
    name: "name1",
    price: "2",
    currency: "€",
    quantity: "2",
  },
  {
    img: "ruta2",
    name: "name2",
    price: "3",
    currency: "$",
    quantity: "3",
  }
]

//  let parsedItems = JSON.parse(itemsLS);
// console.log(parsedItems)


for (let i = 0; i < parsedItems.length; i++) {

  let parsedItem = parsedItems[i];
  let cartLSList = document.getElementById('cart');
  let sss = parsedItem.price * parsedItem.quantity;
  cartLSList.innerHTML += `
            <table class="table" border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="cartArt">
                        <td scope="row"><img src="${parsedItem.img}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="imagen" width="250" height="180"></td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle">${parsedItem.name}</td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle"><span class="price2">${parsedItem.price}</span> ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle"><input class="amount" type="number" value="${parsedItem.quantity}" ></td>
                        <td scope="row" class="align-middle">$ <span class="totalsub">${sss}</span> ${parsedItem.currency}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>   
            </table> 
        `
  document.querySelectorAll(".amount").forEach((x) => x.addEventListener('input', function() {
    let totalsub = x.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".totalsub")
    let price = x.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".price2")
    totalsub.textContent = parseFloat(price.textContent) * x.value
  }))

}
```

```html
<div id="cart"></div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ademas super bien explicado. mil gracias ya tengo idea de como implementar cuando tenga esto mismo en otras ideas que tengo, mil gracias

Comment: Y si quiero sumar esos valores en un total general como podria hacerlo

Comment: Eso es una nueva pregunta que te pedirán que muestres lo que hayas intentado, lo siento.  Pista: En el HTML Crea un nuevo `<div>` que contenga un <span> con un **id** único que contendrá el resultado total de todos los subtotales. Y en el javascript créate una nueva función que se llame algo así como recalcularTotal() y dentro, usando la misma técnica del `querySelectorAll(".amount").forEach((x)` intenta recorrer todos las clases `subtotal` recogiendo sus valores y se los vas sumando en cada ciclo, para mostrarlo en ese nuevo **id** del nuevo **span** ya fuera del bucle de la nueva función

Comment: Pruébalo por tu cuenta tal como te he explicado y si no te sale lo pones todo en una nueva pregunta con lo que has intentado y el error que te da.

Comment: Creo que entendi bien, muchisimas gracias voy a intentarlo si :D

Comment: tuve que publicar me esta dando una paliza javascript :(

Comment: que cosa más rara has hecho alli... y ademas no me has hecho ni caso de lo que te he dicho que hicieras, jeje

Answer (score 0):

El id de un elemento debe ser único, podrías crear tus inputs con una CLASE y obtener todos los elementos con esa clase

Document.getElementsByClassName('nombre_de_la_clse')

```javascript
for (var i = 0; i < ELEMENTOS.length; i++) {
    ELEMENTOS.item(i).addEventListener('input', function() {
        console.log("ola")
    })
 }
```

Comment: me tira este error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at cart.js:107:51

Comment: le saque el id y le puse class="amount"

Comment: @OscarMartinez  getElementsByClassName te devuelve un grupo de elementos, no uno solo, ahora tienes que iterar entre cada elemento y añadirle el listener, ya edite mi respuesta para que veas como pudieras iterar por los elementos.